# Only insert MySQL record if that exact one doesn't allready exist

Tags: php, mysql

Maybe it's just me, but I couldn't find an answer to the exact problem I'm having anywhere else. I have a function that inserts a record in my db like this:

```
function createOpdrachtInstance($opdracht, $bedrijf, $deelnemer) {
    $db = dbConnection();
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $query = "INSERT INTO opdrachten_deelnemers (`opdracht_id`,`bedrijf_id`,`deelnemer_id`,`flag`) VALUES (:opdracht_id,:bedrijf_id,:deelnemer_id,:flag)";
            $q = $db->prepare($query);
            $q->execute(array(':opdracht_id'=>$opdracht,
                              ':bedrijf_id'=>$bedrijf,
                              ':deelnemer_id'=>$deelnemer,
                              ':flag'=>0));
}
```

Works fine. But if a record that is exactly the same allready exists (all rows except id) it shouldn't be inserted. I have found how this works for 1 row but not how it works for multiple rows. How can I implement this in my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO opdrachten_deelnemers (`opdracht_id`,`bedrijf_id`,`deelnemer_id`,`flag`) VALUES (:opdracht_id,:bedrijf_id,:deelnemer_id,:flag)";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You need an unqiue index on all 4 columns also.

Comment: The combination of the three should be unique. This seems to make it so another record cannot have any of the values that are present in another record.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you meant columns rather than rows " (all rows except id) "? If this were me I would use a storedprocedure which has the logic test within to find if a record with these values aready exists. If the record exists, do nothing else add record.